# Setup nginx if index is not in same folder as the rest of the web app

Tags: nginx

In my \homepage\app\views is lying my index.html, which acan be loaded if i start localhost. now the problem is that i cant figure out how to link to css files since they are lying under: homepage\app\assets\stylesheets

And my Php is lying under : homepage\testApp

```
index  /index.scala.html;
root homepage\app\views;
location / {


        }
```

the code above is working which links to index, but it cant load css, javalibrarys or anything else. Any ideas how i can link to them?

P.S. I am a beginner to nginx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[# serve static files](http://wiki.nginx.org/FullExample)

```
  location ~ ^/(images|javascript|js|css|flash|media|static)/  {
      root    homepage\app\assets\stylesheets;
              *#/var/www/virtual/big.server.com/htdocs;*
      expires 30d;
    }
```

if you need some special files serving from this directory you can simply add them to this list.

About php: Nginx was designed for serving static files. Therefore it can not handle php files. For php files you need to use a backed. Here you have two ordinary solutions:
apache(httpd) or php5-fpm.

```
 server { # php/fastcgi
    listen       80;
    server_name  domain1.com www.domain1.com;
    access_log   logs/domain1.access.log  main;
    root         html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:1025;
    }
```